# Where/How to store or generate the Client Secrets?

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am using C# .NET with the YouTubeAPI-Nuget Package.

The project is a Desktop application (Avalonia) and I need access to the YouTube channel of the User (to change for example Video Titles).

I don't understand how or where I need to store the client secrets or if I can generate them or how I am going to distribute the program without users having access to my client secrets.

Does every user who wants to use my program need an own client secrets file? If so, how do I autogenerate that? (because I don't want to manually generate client secrets for every user who wants to use it)

And if they only need the one client secrets, then how do I distribute that without putting the file in plain text into the installation folder?

I really don't know and can't find anything on how this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how or where I need to store the client secrets or if I can generate them or how I am going to distribute the program without users having access to my client secrets.

As you have a desktop application, when you compile it ensure that it is compiled as part of the application do not send for example clientsecret.json as a file along with your application, like a dll.  It should be compiled into your application and distributed that way.  If you want to go even more OTT you could store it on and endpoint on your server and have your desktop app fetch it whenever it runs or when its installed and store the data locally.

> Does every user who wants to use my program need an own client secrets file? If so, how do I autogenerate that? (because I don't want to manually generate client secrets for every user who wants to use it)

No your application should have a single client id and client secrete pair which would be used by all of your users.

> And if they only need the one client secrets, then how do I distribute that without putting the file in plain text into the installation folder?

I haven't seen your code but all you should really need is the client id and the client secret themselves stored as constants in your application somewhere.  You dont actually need the file itself.

Comment: So I need to compile it into the application, a quick search found me app-secrets for ASP.NET. maybe I can use that for .net apps aswell, thank you.

I don't want to use a server.

btw here is the code if you want to look at it: https://github.com/TheSwerik/YouTubeStreamTemplates

Comment: Just remember you cant release your client id as part of an open source project, your not allowed to share it with anyone.

Comment: yes the client id is local on my machine, excluded from git. the problem is only that I need to find out how to distribute the secret safely but that would probably be a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: I have done it twice, once i included it in the project just as a constant and then compiled it with that.   The second time we had it as an api endpoint which the app fetched it from as needed.  it was of course encrypted.

Comment: Aren't there ways to decompile the code? Wouldn't you be able to get it then?

Comment: @Swerik yes and your very smart to ask.  I asked someone on the Google oauth team and this is a gray area.  They have no recommendations as far as it goes with compiled applications.

Comment: So my idea would be to let the CI replace the string value in the C# (.cs) file before publishing. That would not be great but it would be in the gray area, correct?

Comment: sounds like an excellent solution to me most CI even have secret values that you can store in it and then it will just replace it when it builds.  Definitely gray :)

Answer (score 2):

BUT...hash or encrypt the string in your code since opening the executable in Notepad can expose the string in clear text. Best if you obfuscate with string encryption...

Answer (score 0):

Okay the above answers are my answers but I want to share (with code) how exactly I am going to do what they said.

1. My CI is going to get my client id and secret and as secrets (I am using Github Actions).
2. I create string constants in code:

```cs
private const string ClientId = "CLIENT_ID";
private const string ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET";
```

3. Let the CI change these lines of code to the actual Client id and secret

```cs
private const string ClientId = "ACTUAL_CLIENT_ID";
private const string ClientSecret = "ACTUAL_CLIENT_SECRET";
```

4. Let the CI confuscate the resulting dll after `dotnet publish` so that it is harder to decompile this. (I am trying to get ConfuserEx to work)